# Find files with certain name but variable file extension

Tags: php, file

I'd like to be able to select a file by just giving it's name (without extension). For example, I might have a variable `$id` holding `12`. I want to be able to select a file called the-id-in-the-variable, say, `12.png` from a directory, but it may have any one of a number of file extensions, listed below:

- .swf
- .png
- .gif
- .jpg

There is only one occurrence of each ID. I could use a loop and `file_exists()`, but is there a better way?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$matches = glob("12.*");
```

would return an array with all the matching filenames in the current directory. [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) works much the same as wildcard matching at the shell prompt.

Comment: Thanks! So simple... I thought I'd have to some sort of massive PHP script :-P

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Unfortunately, the exact semantics of the `$pattern` parameter is not described in the manual. But it seems your problem can be solved using this function.

Comment: Actually, it is: *"according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells."* ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Quick question to OP here:

What is the file extension of this file: `somefile.tar.gz`? Is it `.gz` or `.tar.gz`? :) I ask because most would answer this question as `.tar.gz`...

Comment: I'd answer `.gz` - it is a GZipped tar archive ;-)

Comment: Thats where people get confused. It's just GZipped archive, who cares of what kind :) You are on right track bro, good luck!